# Why vim tags option change between jumps

Tags: vim, tags

In my .vimrc file I have `set tags=./tags,/usr/include/tags`.Today when I am editing a C source file, I used the Ex command:

`set tags+=../tags`

And after that I could jump between tags defined in `../tags` successfully, but when I jumped to another file, the `tags` option became to the original value `./tags,/usr/include/tags`.In the documentation it is said that `tags` is a global-local option.Since I didn't use the `setlocal` comamnd, why would the option change?

Comment: Because of an `autocmd`, maybe? Try `:verbose set tags?` in all those files.